# change numercial name of columns by skipping first one

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a sample dataframe:

```
df = 

      A     0   1   2   3   4   5 

     11     2   3   4   5   6   7
     11     2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Desired output:

```
df = 

      A   1   1.1   2   2.2   3   3.3  

     11   2     3   4     5   6     7
     11   2     3   4     5   6     7
```

Change from `1,2,3,4 ... max number` to `1, 1.1, 2, 2.2, 3, 3.3 ... max number`

Comment: where are you getting these numbers from --> 1,1.1,2,2.2,3...... ?

Comment: I want to get them

Comment: What is your use case? And why do you want the numbers that way?

Comment: Also, please mention what you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create list of possible values and assign back, filtering by `c[:len(df.columns) - 1]` is necessary for general solution working also with unpair changed columns names:

```
c = [y for x in range(1, (len(df.columns)) // 2 + 1)  for y in (x, x + x / 10)]

df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + c[:len(df.columns) - 1]
#if always pair number of renamed columns
#df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + c
print (df)


    A  1  1.1  2  2.2  3  3.3
0  11  2    3  4    5  6    7
1  11  2    3  4    5  6    7
```